# CSS Flex - Columns that switch to rows if content is wider?

Tags: css, layout, flexbox

I am trying to achieve the following layout:

```
<Column 1, 50%> <Column 2, 50%>
```

Column 2 might have longer content depending on some conditions, in which case it should now be pushed to the second row and take a 100% width. Meaning both will be rows now.

```
<Row 1 (was Column 1), 100%>
<Row 2 (was Column 2), 100%>
```

Right now I am stuck at equal width columns, and with wider content the second column grows vertically.

Comment: Why you have to do this? Why not simply set lg (or md) size?

Comment: The first div has a text input, and the second has a button in it. The button could grow depending on which language we're showing the content in. (Product requirement, I am no one to decide that!)

Comment: lg/md? Sorry please can you elaborate?

Comment: Sorry i was thoughing using Bootstrap's concepts. With this i mean setting different width of Columns depending on screen width. Why not using media queries?

Comment: No problem. I doubt media queries will work here because we are working on dynamic content widths rather than viewport sizes.

Answer (score 3):

Just a flex-box layout with `flex-wrap` ?

```css
.my-layout {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.my-layout > * {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  /* optional: determine the minimum width of the cell before it breaks into the next line */
  min-width: 45%;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-layout">
  <div style="background-color: salmon;">First Line</div>
  <div style="background-color: steelblue;">Second Line</div>
</div>

<br>

<div class="my-layout">
  <div style="background-color: salmon;">First Line First Line First Line First Line First Line First Line First Line First Line </div>
  <div style="background-color: steelblue;">Second Line</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this, although the wrapping works, my 2nd column now by default render as the second row, and takes 100% width, and the first one stays 50% and on the left side.

Comment: How do I leave space in between the columns?

Comment: Add margin: 0 10px;; to .my-layout > *